# How should I handle intermediate build files between jobs in Azure Pipelines?

Tags: azure-pipelines

I have three jobs in my Azure Pipeline which each builds some files (`cmake --build .`, `npm run build`, etc.).

I have a single job which depends on the above which packages the three into an installer with `nsis`. It basically zips them up into one file.

Currently, this works by uploading the first three build *folders* as [pipeline artifacts](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/artifacts/pipeline-artifacts?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml), and then downloading them in the fourth job.

This works, but then I have a bunch of unnecessary build folders cluttering my "artifacts" page, and taking up unnecessary storage.

There's no way to delete artifacts from the YAML, so what's the solution here? How do I use pipeline artifacts in my pipeline, but leave them out of permanent storage?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're using them correctly. They are designed to be used as transient storage to share resources between jobs / stages. The pipeline artifacts aren't permanent, they will be removed from storage when the pipeline run is tidied up as defined in your [retention policy](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/policies/retention?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml). So by default your old runs will be deleted after 30 days.

If you want to permanently store the Zip file from your final job. You should publish that to Azure Artifacts, or some other binary repository like Artifactory or Nexus, or a file share.